# In GoogleAppEngine oauth flow how to get Web App credentials

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a web app in Google App Engine (with Flask) that needs to ask the user for permissions.
I followed [this explanation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer) and it got me working great.

But how do I get the secret_file (or client_config) credentials?

All examples I saw used a local file - but that is not production safe! Is there any way to get it from the application credentials?

I also tried using `oauth2client.client.GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()` but that seems to be a service account which I can't use.

Answer (score 0):

Creation of web app authorization credentials is discussed [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#creatingcred).

Once you are done with the form, client_secret.json file will be generated and is downloadable via the  [API Console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials).

There will be a 'Download JSON' button at the right of the OAuth Client credential you created and at the upper part of the page when you click on the Client ID.

From this [documentation](http://%20https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#creatingclient), it is explained how to construct the authorization request using google-auth-oauthlib.flow module.

> In Python, call the from_client_secrets_file method to retrieve the
>   client ID from a client_secret.json file. (You can also use the
>   from_client_config method, which passes the client configuration as it
>   originally appeared in a client secrets file but doesn't access the
>   file itself.)

Comment: Tahnks for the response, but this in no way answers the question. My problem is not with creating the flow, but with the security of the credentials file.